# What is the best way to fin and use a template in cakephp 3

Tags: templates, themes, cakephp-3.0

i'm new in cakephp and I have started with version 3. I want to build a beautifull app and because I'm not good in design, I would really like to use a free template or buy one that I can use within cakephp.

So, I would really appreciate all your propositions and ideas or best practises. The easy way will be the best because I don't have a lot of time with this project. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a lot of time like you mentioned, the easiest way to go ahead and get started is to paste a lot of the code in your default.ctp layout inside of src/Template/Layout/default.ctp.

You'll notice there are some lines of PHP already in there that are relevant to fetching blocks of css, meta tags, and other bits of code that could potentially exist throughout your project.

Find the main layout of the theme your trying to use - the one that will be consistent across most of the pages. That's the one you'll use for default.ctp. Compare what's already in default.ctp and make the comparable adjustments around the HTML in that document while keeping the important lines of PHP there as well.

For other important pages like a login or registration page, just create a new document for those, like 'login.ctp', then inside the function that loads the page (maybe 'login' inside of UsersController'), change the default layout with this line of code:

```
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('login'); // without the .ctp ending
```

This way you can create one-off layouts that don't really match any other page.